# How can I know which docker host my CLI returned the information from?

Tags: docker

Scenario: I have 2 docker daemons listening on separate unix socket and TCP socket.

Question: If I run a command, say `docker service ls` then how can I know which docker host my CLI returned the information from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [`docker` CLI](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cli/#configuration-files), you need to use the `-H` option in order to specify the socket you want `docker` to talk to.

Or you can set the environment variable `DOCKER_HOST` (Daemon socket to connect to).
If `docker service ls` is working, that means that variable was set. Its value would indicate to which docker daemon it is talking to.